# Declare and define class within a namespace

Tags: c++

I defined a namespace and a class within the namespace as follows:

ns.h

```
namespace Test
{
    class HelloWorld;
};
```

HelloWorld.h

```
#include "ns.h"

class Test::HelloWorld
{
public:
    static void print();
};
```

HelloWorld.cpp

```
#include "HelloWorld.h"

void Test::HelloWorld::print()
{
    printf("HelloWorld\n");
}
```

And Test.cpp

```
#include "ns.h"

using namespace Test;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HelloWorld::print();

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled and got these errors: `error C2027: use of undefined type 'Test::HelloWorld'` and `error C3861: 'print': identifier not found`

I would like to separate namespace and HelloWorld into different files for more succinct but it seems not work. How can I deal with this?

Comment: You need to wrap the class definition in `namespace Test {  }`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Could you please give me more details? I tried to wrap HelloWorld declaration (HelloWorld.h) & definition (HelloWorld.cpp) but it still does not work

Comment: Can you please provide which compiler and version you're using?

Comment: @JohnBurger VC++ 2008

Comment: You'll need to include "HelloWorld.h" in Test.cpp (instead of "ns.h"), or some other kind of change so that the definition of the Test::HelloWorld class is available.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce the issue](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:'-c+-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O2',source:'%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Anamespace+Test%0A%7B%0A++++class+HelloWorld%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+Test::HelloWorld%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++static+void+print()%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+Test::HelloWorld::print()%0A%7B%0A++++std::printf(%22HelloWorld%5Cn%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++using+namespace+Test%3B%0A++HelloWorld::print()%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

Comment: You are missing `#include <cstdio>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ns.h** and **HelloWorld.h** do not require changes

**HelloWorld.cpp**:

```
#include "HelloWorld.h"

// This was missing, you need it for printf
#include <cstdio>

void Test::HelloWorld::print() {
    printf("HelloWorld\n");
}
```

**Test.cpp**:

```
// No need to include "ns.h" here
//#include "ns.h"

// You need to include "HelloWorld.h" for Test::HelloWorld::print
#include "HelloWorld.h"

// Now you can refer to Test::HelloWorld::print as HelloWorld::print
using namespace Test;

// I am not using Visual Studio so I changed main
// int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    HelloWorld::print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, the key point is that I mistakenly include ns.h instead of HelloWorld.h in Test.cpp - as pointed out by @wuggy. Anyway, thank you for your clear answer.